# how do I keep one movieclip on top of another in actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, z-index, addchild

so, let´s say I `addChild(mc1);` at the beginning of the code, how do I keep it on top of `addChild(mc2);` when I add more stuff later on in the code? by default mc2 will cover mc1... I have tried z-indexes, but I have not completely grasped how to use it in my situation... help?

thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A couple of suggestions:

1. Use `addChildAt(mc1, 0)` `addChildAt(mc2, 1)`. You can use `addChildAt` to state a specific 'layer' to add a movieclip to.
2. Whenever you add anything else, re-add the movieclip you want to keep on top, ie:

   addChild(mc1); // adds first mc

   addChild(mc2); // adds second mc on top of first

   addChild(mc1); // re-draws mc1 to the top layer (does not add again, just brings to top!)

Comment: Sorry for the poor formatting in the 2nd solution, couldn't get the code tag to work =/

Answer (score 2):

You could also create a parent sprite under "mc1", then add "mc2" and everything else to that parent. Whatever is under that parent sprite will always remain under mc1 then and you won't need to worry about manually moving mc1 to the front of the display stack.

```
// during when mc1 is first added
var parentSprite:Sprite = new Sprite();
this.addChild(parentSprite);
this.addChild(mc1);



// later in your code, whatever is added to "parentSprite" will always be displayed under mc1
parentSprite.addChild(mc2);
parentSprite.addChild(mc3);
parentSprite.addChild(mc4);
.
.
.
etc
```

Comment: I already fixed it with addChildAt and made a working system for it, so that it always checks it and adds it top. thanks anyways, I bet this will be useful later when I need it :)

Answer (score 0):

movieclips have a three coordinates system in their class, so unless I'm mistaken, you can try altering mc1.z to be higher than mc2.z

Comment: didnt work... isn´t z depth, so completely different from the problem?  :S